# How to draw intersect of line sphere?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, intersections

How to draw intersect of line sphere?[image]

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109696/stereographic-projections could help

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 24):

One way is to use spherical coordinates to define the two points A and B on the sphere, and then draw a dashed line between them and to use calc to extend the line beyond the sphere.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\makeatletter
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375604/121799
% spherical coordinates 
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{radius}{\def\myradius{#1}}
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{theta}{\def\mytheta{#1}}
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{phi}{\def\myphi{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{z spherical}{% %%%rotation around x
    \setkeys{z sphericalkeys}{#1}%
    \pgfpointxyz{\myradius*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi)}{\myradius*sin(\mytheta)*sin(\myphi)}{\myradius*cos(\mytheta)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{00} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:O] (O) at (0,0,0){};
\shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.3] (O) circle (4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[thick,dashed] (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=120,phi=140) 
coordinate (p1) -- (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=50,phi=240) coordinate (p2);
\draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi+360,smooth,samples=60]  (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=90,phi=\x);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180,smooth,samples=60]  (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=90,phi=\x);
\end{scope}
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:B] at (p2){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:A] at (p1){};
\draw[thick] let \p1=($(p2)-(p1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in (p2) -- ++(\n1:2.5)
(p1) -- ++(\n1+180:2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Almost forgot the animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\makeatletter
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375604/121799
% spherical coordinates 
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{radius}{\def\myradius{#1}}
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{theta}{\def\mytheta{#1}}
\define@key{z sphericalkeys}{phi}{\def\myphi{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{z spherical}{% %%%rotation around x
    \setkeys{z sphericalkeys}{#1}%
    \pgfpointxyz{\myradius*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi)}{\myradius*sin(\mytheta)*sin(\myphi)}{\myradius*cos(\mytheta)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,9,...,354}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{0} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\path (-5,-6) rectangle (5,7);
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:O] (O) at (0,0,0){};
\shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.3] (O) circle (4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[thick,dashed] (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=120,phi=140) 
coordinate (p1) -- (z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=20,phi=240+\X) coordinate (p2);
\draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi+360,smooth,samples=60] 
(z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=90,phi=\x);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180,smooth,samples=60] 
(z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=90,phi=\x);
\draw[thin,gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=60] 
(z spherical cs:radius=4,theta=20,phi=\x);
\end{scope}
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:B] at (p2){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below right:A] at (p1){};
\draw[thick] let \p1=($(p2)-(p1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in (p2) -- ++(\n1:2.5)
(p1) -- ++(\n1+180:2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that the spurious lines are not there on the pdf, they come only after the conversion to gif, and I do not know why nor how to get rid of them.)

### *Addendum*

Spurious lines into animated gif above come from ghostscript (a bug with shadings?).

By using `pdftopnm` then `convert`, spurious lines disappear:

- `pdftoppm -r 100 tikz-3d-sphere.pdf temp -png`
- `convert -delay 4 temp-* tikz-3d-sphere.gif`
- `rm temp-*`

[image]

Comment: +1 excellent marmot. For my character not edited the codes of the best. The first code must be edited correctly because it is divided into two parts.

Comment: @Sebastiano Mille grazie!

Comment: You will notice that the spurious lines disappear if you delete the line : `%\shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.3] (O) circle (4);`
But as a result, we can no longer see the sphere...

Comment: @AndréC I am aware of that. But an invisible sphere is not quite what I want.... ;-)

Comment: @marmot I draw the sphere center at `O(0,0,0)`, radius 5,  and the line passing though two points on the sphere are `A(0,-4,-3)` and `B(-3,0,4)`.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sphere center at `O(0,0,0)` and radius `R = 5`. We know that two points `A(0,-4,-3)` and `B(-3,0,4)` on the sphere. I copied some lines at here 
[How can I draw this cylinder with 3D?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480718/how-can-i-draw-this-cylinder-with-3d/480728#480728)

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \def\myr{5}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,-4,-3);
\coordinate (B) at (-3,0,4);
\coordinate (C) at ($(B)!1.3!(A)$); 
\coordinate (D) at ($(A)!1.3!(B)$); 
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]

    \draw[dashed] (\tdplotmainphi:\myr) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:\myr);

    \draw[thick] (\tdplotmainphi:\myr) coordinate(BR) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180:\myr)
    coordinate(BL);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer] 
\fill[ball color=orange,opacity=1] (O) circle (\myr); 
\end{scope}

\draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\draw[thick] (A) -- (C) (B) -- (D);

 \foreach \point/\position in {A/below,B/left,O/below} {\fill (\point) circle (1.5pt); \node[\position=1pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]