# How to draw in 3 dimensions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hellow all guy.help me How to draw in 3 dimensions ?[image]

Comment: You could use TikZ or [PStricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). Generally, you should put a small code here that shows you've tried something.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do? For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446271/how-to-draw-intersect-of-line-sphere has such a nice answer, but you never accepted an answer to any of your questions :(

Comment: Besides what's been said in the comments above, note that the diagram in your post can easily be constructed in 2D, for instance with `tikz`.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment above, I suggested that it could be done constructed with a 2D vector diagram.

Here's a sample in Tikz (I'll leave you to fill in the finer details yourself):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->,gray!50!black] (0,5) node[above]{$z$} -- (0,0) --(-3,-4) node[left]{$x$};
\draw [->,gray!50!black] (0,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(4,0)--(2.25,-3)--(-2.25,-3)--(0,0);
\draw[thick] (2.25,-3)--(2.25,1.5)--(0,0);
\draw[dashed] (-2.25,-3)--(2.25,1.5)--(4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]