# Intersection of a sphere and a plane knowing equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying draw a circle is intersection of a plane has equation `2 x − 2 y + z − 15 = 0` and the equation of the sphere is `( x − 1)^2 + ( y + 1)^ 2 + ( z − 2)^ 2 − 25 = 0`.
[image]

The plane cut the sphere is a circle with centre `(3,-3,3` and radius `r = 4`.

I can't draw the  circle. I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,border = 2 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\path
      coordinate (T) at (3,-3,3)
      coordinate (I) at (1,-1,2);

\foreach \v/\position in {T/above,I/below} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\v) circle (0.7pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
}

\draw[dashed] (T) circle[radius={4}];

\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{5}%
  \fill[ball color=purple, opacity=1.0] (I) circle (\R); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I draw the circle?

Comment: I guess the issue is rather basic: you need to specify the plane in which the circle is in. Your plane has a nontrivial normal vector but you draw the circle in the `xy` plane, which is why it does not match up.

Comment: The plane has normal vector is (2,-2,1).

Comment: Yes, I know. Naively I would think that it is better to switch to a local coordinate system in which the center of the sphere is at `(0,0,0)` and the normal goes in the z direction, and then just rotate the view. Do your know [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/121799). It will allow you to draw the intersection in such a way that the visible stretch is distinguished from the hidden one. (If you do not like `pgfplot`, you could also use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439153/121799).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know the normal `n` of the plane and the radius of the circle. Call two vectors that are orthogonal to `n` and orthogonal to each other `u` and `v`. Then the circle is given by

```
 gamma(t) = I + n + r * cos(t) * u + r* sin(t) * v,
```

where `n` fulfills the length constraint `n^2+r^2=R^2`, where `R` is the radius of the sphere and `r` the radius of the circle. Your vector `n` satisfies this constraint already, so we do not have to change its normalization.

Now we need to figure out what the visible and invisible stretches are. Any point on the sphere has either a positive or negative projection on the normal vector on the screen

```
n_screen =({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},{-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{cos(\tdplotmaintheta)});
```

So we need to find the zeros of the projection `gamma(t).n_screen`. This can be accomplished by letting Ti*k*Z find the intersections. Of course we do not really draw the paths here, and use `overlay` for them not to screw up the bounding box. Notice that the current version assumes that there are two zeros, so if you drastically change the view angles, this version won't work any more.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={dicri(\t,\th,\ph,\R)=
sin(\th)*sin(\ph)*(2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)+\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18))-
sin(\th)*cos(\ph)*(-2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)-\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18))+
cos(\th)*(1-4*\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18));}]
\path
      coordinate (T) at (3,-3,3)
      coordinate (I) at (1,-1,2)
      coordinate (n) at (2,-2,1)
      coordinate (u) at ({1/sqrt(2)},{1/sqrt(2)},0)
      coordinate (v) at ({1/sqrt(18)},{-1/sqrt(18)},{-4/sqrt(18)});
      % the coordinatesn, u and v are not really used here

\foreach \v/\position in {T/above,I/below} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\v) circle (0.7pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
}
% \draw[red,thick,-latex] (0,0,0) --
% ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},
% {-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{cos(\tdplotmaintheta)});
% normal to screen
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{5}%
  \fill[ball color=purple, opacity=1.0] (I) circle (\R);
  % determine the zeros of dicri
  \path[overlay,name path=dicri] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,samples=73]
  ({\x*1pt},{dicri(\x,\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,4)});
  \path[overlay,name path=zero] (0,0) -- (360pt,0);
  \path[name intersections={of=dicri and zero,total=\t}]
  let \p1=(intersection-1),\p2=(intersection-2) in
  \pgfextra{\xdef\xmin{\x1}\xdef\xmax{\x2}};
\end{scope}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=\xmin:\xmax,samples=73,smooth] 
 ({1+2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)+\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {-1-2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)-\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {2+1-4*\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)});
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=\xmax:\xmin+360,samples=73,smooth] 
 ({1+2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)+\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {-1-2+\R*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)-\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {2+1-4*\R*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a plane, using your nicer vectors `u` and `v` from the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91494/discussion-between-minhthien-2016-and-marmot).

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,backgrounds,intersections} 
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799
\tikzset{
  use path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, 
  declare function={dicri(\t,\th,\ph,\R)=% 
  sin(\th)*sin(\ph)*(2+\R*cos(\t)/3+2*\R*sin(\t)/3)-%
  sin(\th)*cos(\ph)*(-2 +2*\R*cos(\t)/3 + \R*sin(\t)/3)+%
  cos(\th)*(1+2*\R*cos(\t)/3-2*\R*sin(\t)/3);}] 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{5}% 
  \path  coordinate (T) at (3,-3,3) 
   coordinate (I) at (1,-1,2) 
   coordinate (n) at (2,-2,1) 
   coordinate (u) at (1, 2, 2) 
   coordinate (v) at (2, 1, -2); 
  % the coordinatesn, u and v are not really used here 
   \path[tdplot_screen_coords,shift={(I)},use as bounding box] (-1.2*\R,-1.2*\R)rectangle (1.2*\R,1.2*\R);   

  \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,I/below} { 
   \draw[fill=black] (\v) circle (0.7pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
  } 
  % \draw[red,thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- 
  % ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)}, 
  % {-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}); 
  % normal to screen 
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer] 
   \fill[ball color=green, opacity=0.8] (I) circle (\R); 
   % determine the zeros of dicri 
   \path[overlay,name path=dicri] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,samples=73] 
   ({\x*1pt},{dicri(\x,\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,4)}); 
   \path[overlay,name path=zero] (0,0) -- (360pt,0); 
   \path[name intersections={of=dicri and zero,total=\t}] 
   let \p1=(intersection-1),\p2=(intersection-2) in 
   \pgfextra{\xdef\tmin{\x1}\xdef\tmax{\x2}}; 
  \end{scope} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\SmallR}{4} 
  \draw[dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=\tmin:\tmax,samples=50,smooth] 
   ({1+2+\SmallR*cos(\t)/3+2*\SmallR*sin(\t)/3}, 
   {-1-2 +2*\SmallR*cos(\t)/3+ \SmallR*sin(\t)/3}, 
   {2+1+2*\SmallR*cos(\t)/3 - 2*\SmallR*sin(\t)/3 }); 
  \draw[thick,save path=\pathA] plot[variable=\t,domain=\tmax:\tmin+360,samples=50,smooth] 
   ({1+2+\SmallR*cos(\t)/3+2*\SmallR*sin(\t)/3}, 
   {-1-2 +2*\SmallR*cos(\t)/3+ \SmallR*sin(\t)/3}, 
   {2+1+2*\SmallR*cos(\t)/3 - 2*\SmallR*sin(\t)/3 }); 
  \path ({1+2+\SmallR*cos(\tmin)/3+2*\SmallR*sin(\tmin)/3}, 
   {-1-2 +2*\SmallR*cos(\tmin)/3+ \SmallR*sin(\tmin)/3}, 
   {2+1+2*\SmallR*cos(\tmin)/3 - 2*\SmallR*sin(\tmin)/3 }) coordinate (pmin)
   ({1+2+\SmallR*cos(\tmax)/3+2*\SmallR*sin(\tmax)/3}, 
   {-1-2 +2*\SmallR*cos(\tmax)/3+ \SmallR*sin(\tmax)/3}, 
   {2+1+2*\SmallR*cos(\tmax)/3 - 2*\SmallR*sin(\tmax)/3 }) coordinate (pmax);
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
   \clip[shift={(I)}] (-1.2*\R,-1.2*\R)rectangle (1.2*\R,1.2*\R);   
   \path[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.4,even odd rule] let \p1=($(pmin)-(I)$),\p2=($(pmax)-(I)$),
   \p3=($(pmax)-(pmin)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
   \n3={atan2(\y3,\x3)}
    in [use path=\pathA]  (pmin) arc(\n1:\n2-360:\R) 
    (0,-6) -- ++(\n3:{12cm/sin(\n3)}) -- ++(\n3+90:{12cm/sin(\n3)})
    -- ++(\n3+180:{12cm/sin(\n3)}) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I find the points `u` and `v`? The way to find.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 They need to be orthogonal to `n` and to each other.

Comment: And how about the number `4.01`?

Comment: I can find `u = (1, -4, -10)` and `v = (8, 7, -2)`.

Comment: Can we reduce the line `({1+2+4.01*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)+4.01*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {-1-2+4.01*cos(\t)*1/sqrt(2)-4.01*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)},
 {2+1-4*4.01*sin(\t)*1/sqrt(18)})` as `I + n + 4.01* cos(t) * u + 4.01*sin(\t)*v`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I tried but I did not succeed very quickly. The calc syntax does not seem to harmonize with plots. Most likely I did something stupid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91494/discussion-between-minhthien-2016-and-marmot).

Answer (score 6):

Many thanks to Schrödinger's cat about `3dtools`. In this answer, I use *Mathematica* to find coordinates of three points `A, B, C` and draw circle (ABC). I use `tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere` at   [here](https://github.com/matthias-wolff/tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere) to draw style of line of the circle (ABC).

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=5;
}]
    \path   (3,-3,3) coordinate (T)
    (1,-1,2) coordinate (I) 
    (1, {1/5 *(-23 - 2* sqrt(11))}, {1/5 *(19 - 4 *sqrt(11))}) coordinate (A)
    (1, {1/5 *(-23 + 2* sqrt(11))}, {1/5 *(19 + 4 *sqrt(11))}) coordinate (B)
    ({1/4* (13 + sqrt(119))}, {1/4 *(-13 + sqrt(119))}, 2) coordinate (C);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords] 
\fill[ball color=green, opacity=0.8] (I) circle (R);
    \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(I)}]
\path[overlay] [3d coordinate={(A-B)=(A)-(B)},
3d coordinate={(A-C)=(A)-(C)},
3d coordinate={(myn)=(A-B)x(A-C)},
3d coordinate={(A-T)=(A)-(T)}];
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myaxisangles}{axisangles("(myn)")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{{\myaxisangles}[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{{\myaxisangles}[1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mygamma}{-acos(sqrt(TD("(A-T)o(A-T)"))/R)}
\tdplotCsDrawCircle[tdplotCsFront/.style={thick}]{R}{\myalpha}{\mybeta}{\mygamma} 
\end{scope} 

\foreach \p in {I,T,B}
\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1.5 pt);
\foreach \p/\g in {I/0,T/-90,B/30}
\path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
\draw[dashed] (I) -- (T) -- (B) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I add this because you asked me to use the `3d circle through 3 points` pic here. It can be used after we have three points. These points can be constructed by adding vectors of length 4, the radius, to `T` which lie in the plane of the circle. These vectors are taken from the other answer, and rescaled.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysq}{4/3}
\path   (3,-3,3) coordinate (T)
      (1,-1,2) coordinate (I) 
      (1, 2, 2) coordinate (u)  
      (2, 1, -2) coordinate (v)
      [3d coordinate={(A)=(T)+\mysq*(u)}]
      [3d coordinate={(B)=(T)+\mysq*(v)}]
      [3d coordinate={(C)=(T)-\mysq*(u)}];

\foreach \v/\position in {T/above,I/below} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\v) circle (0.7pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
}

\path[dashed] pic{3d circle through 3 points={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)}}};

\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{5}%
  \fill[ball color=purple, opacity=1.0] (I) circle (\R); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote `pgfmathsetmacro{\mysq}{4/3}`. How can I find the number 4/3?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 If I remember correctly they were chosen such that A, B and C sit on the sphere, i.e. (A-I)^2=5^2 and so on.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat Perhaps, it's `r/IH`. We can use Mathematica to find coordinates of three points `A, B, C`.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The factor 4/3 is very simple. We want `(T+a u-I)^2=5^2`. Since `(T-I)` is perpendicular to `u`, this means that `(T-I)^2+a^2 u^2=9 (1+a^2)=25`, or `a^2=(25-9)/9=16/9`, so `a=4/3`.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, `Asymptote` version:

```
// spherexplane.asy
//
// run 
//   asy -f pdf -render=4 -noprc spherexplane.asy
// to get a standalone raster spherexplane.pdf
//
import solids;
size(8cm); size3(100,100);
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(66,40,-9),zoom=0.9);
currentlight=Headlamp;

pen linePen=darkblue+1.3bp;
pen dotPen= darkblue+3bp;
pen dashPen=1bp+linetype(new real[]{4,3})+linecap(0);

// Eqn of the sphere (x - 1)^2 + (y + 1)^ 2 + (z - 2)^ 2 - 25 = 0
triple O=(1,-1,2);
real R=5;

// Eqn of the plane  2 x - 2 y + z - 15 = 0
triple fp(real x, real y){return (x,y,- 2 x + 2 y + 15);}

triple Np=unit((2,-2,1)); // plane normal
triple A=fp(0,0);  // any point on the plane
triple C=O+dot(A-O,Np)*Np; // center of the circle cross section

real d=abs(C-O);
real r=sqrt(R^2-d^2);

guide3 baseArc=Arc(O,O+Np*R,O-Np*R,normal=cross(Z,Np));
revolution b=revolution(O,baseArc,axis=Np); // spherical surface
skeleton s;
real t=acos(d/R)/pi; // fraction of the arc length at the cutting point
b.transverse(s,reltime(b.g,t),P=currentprojection);
guide3 circCut=s.transverse.back[0] & s.transverse.front[0] & cycle;

triple D=relpoint(circCut,0.6);

draw(surface(b),paleblue+opacity(0.3));
draw(surface(circCut),orange+opacity(0.3));

draw(s.transverse.front,linePen);
draw(s.transverse.back, dashPen);

draw(O--C--D, dashPen);

dot("$O$",O,dotPen);
dot(Label("$C$",unit(C-O)),C,dotPen);
dot("$D$",D,dotPen);

xaxis3(xmin=0,xmax=1,red,above=true);
yaxis3(ymin=0,ymax=1,deepgreen,above=true);
zaxis3(zmin=0,zmax=1,blue,above=true);
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I am still learning your asymptote answers.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @g.kov Does asymptote always draw the hidden parts dashed automatically?

Comment: @minhthien_2016: I don't think it does.

Comment: @g.kov Is Asymptote Is real 3D and TikZ Is not?

Comment: @minhthien_2016: I'm not an expert in `TikZ`, but as far as I'm aware of,
`Asymptote` has more `3d`-related features, for example, 
built-in 3D-viewer, `3D prc` embedded in `.pdf` file,
3D `html` output in `webgl` format.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I use  `3dtools` like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line cap=butt,line join=round,declare function={R=5;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}] 
    \path[overlay]
        (0,0,15) coordinate (A)
        (1,-1,2)  coordinate (I);
        \draw[3d/screen coords] (I) circle[radius=R]; 
        \path[overlay,3d/plane with normal={(2,-2,1) through (A) named p}];
        \path[3d/project={(I) on p}] coordinate (T);
\pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(I)}, P={(T)}}};
 \path foreach \p/\g in {I/-90,T/90}
 {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]