# to plot the plane of intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $x+z=0$

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot the plane of intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $x+z=0$.

**See the edit**

I have tried to plot it with the help of https://tikz.net/parametric-sphere/.

My plane of intersection is not very clearly visible. Also I am not sure where this code is correctly developed.

Please help.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1pt}
%
\begin{document}
    %
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        % Parametric equations of the sphere
        \tikzmath{function equis(\r,\p,\t) {return \r * sin(\p r) * cos(\t r);};}
        \tikzmath{function ye(\r,\p,\t) {return \r * sin(\p r) * sin(\t r);};}
        \tikzmath{function zeta(\r,\p,\t) {return \r * cos(\p r);};}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tcero}{0.0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiInit}{0.0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiMid}{0.5*pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiEnd}{pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaInit}{0.5*pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaMid}{1.85*pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaEnd}{2.5*pi}
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{0.02}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\next}{\tcero+0.5*\step}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sig}{2.0*\step}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radio}{2.0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sigP}{\phiMid+\step}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sigPp}{\sigP+\step}
        % Part of the z axis below the sphere
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,-1.25*\radio) -- (0,0,-\radio);
        % I start to draw the sphere from below
        % Part of the sphere under the plane z = 0
        \foreach \p in {\sigP,\sigPp,...,\phiEnd}{          \draw[gray,thick,opacity=0.15] plot[domain=\thetaInit:\thetaEnd,smooth,variable=\t]                 ({equis(\radio,\p,\t)},{ye(\radio,\p,\t)},{zeta(\radio,\p,\t)});        }
        % Then I draw the part of the coordinate axis that is inside the sphere. 
        %%% Coordinate axis
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5*\radio,0,0) node [below left] {\footnotesize$x$};
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (-1.25*\radio,0,0);
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5*\radio,0) node [right] {\footnotesize$y$};
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1.25*\radio,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-\radio);
        % As a reference, I draw a circumference at z = 0 (phi = pi / 2).
        \draw[black,thick,opacity=0.25] plot[domain=0:2*pi,smooth,variable=\t]              ({equis(\radio,\phiMid,\t)},{ye(\radio,\phiMid,\t)},{zeta(\radio,\phiMid,\t)});
        % As a reference, I draw a circumference at x = 0 (theta = 0).
        %\draw[red,opacity=0.25] plot[domain=0:2*pi,smooth,variable=\t]     ({equis(\radio,\t,0)},{ye(\radio,\t,0)},{zeta(\radio,\t,0)});
        % As a reference, I draw a circumference at y = 0 (theta = pi/2).
        \draw[red,opacity=0.25] plot[domain=0:2*pi,smooth,variable=\t]              ({equis(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{ye(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{zeta(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)});
        %
        % Now I draw the part of the sphere that is behind the axis
        %
        \foreach \p in {\step,\sig,...,\phiMid}{
            \draw[gray,thick,opacity=0.25] plot[domain=\thetaInit:\thetaMid,smooth,variable=\t] 
                ({equis(\radio,\p,\t)},{ye(\radio,\p,\t)},{zeta(\radio,\p,\t)}); 
        }
        % Z axis that is inside the sphere
        % This part has to be in front of the rear part of the sphere
        \draw[thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\radio);
  \draw[black,opacity=0.35,densely dotted] plot[domain=-3*pi/4:3*pi/4,smooth,variable=\t]               ({equis(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{ye(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{zeta(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)});
        %
        % Sphere (the part that is in front of the z axis)
        %
        \foreach \p in {\step,\sig,...,\phiMid}{
            \draw[gray,thick,opacity=0.1] plot[domain=\thetaMid:\thetaEnd,smooth,variable=\t] 
                ({equis(\radio,\p,\t)},{ye(\radio,\p,\t)},{zeta(\radio,\p,\t)}); 
        }
        % Part of the z axis that is above the sphere
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0,\radio) -- (0,0,1.5*\radio) node [above] {\footnotesize$z$};
       \filldraw[
        draw=black,%
        fill=black!20,opacity=0.45%
    ]          (2,2,-2)
            -- (-2,2,-2)
            -- (-2,-2,2)
            -- (2,-2,2)
            -- cycle;
            % As a reference, I draw a circumference at y = 0 (theta = pi/2).
          \draw[black,opacity=0.95] plot[domain=pi/2+pi/4:2*pi-pi/4,smooth,variable=\t]                 ({equis(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{ye(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)},{zeta(\radio,\t,\thetaInit)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edited

```
**\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
    view={35}{15},
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    ticks = none,
    ymin=-2.8,
    ymax=0,
    xmax=2.8,
    xmin=0,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:0)},anchor=north east},
    every axis z label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
    x axis line style=-,
    y axis line style=-,
    z axis line style=-,
    clip=false
  ]
\addplot3[name path=toppath,fill=gray, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=2] (x/4,2,-x/4);
\addplot3[name path=botpath,fill=gray, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=2] (x/4,-2,-x/4);
\addplot [gray] fill between[of=toppath and botpath];
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=0:360,y domain=-90:90,opacity=0.5,
    colormap={bluewhite}{color=(blue) color=(blue!30)}] ({2*cos(y)*cos(x)},
    {2*cos(y)*sin(x)},{2*sin(y)});
\addplot3[samples y=0,domain=0:360,smooth]({2*cos(x)},  {2*sin(x)},0);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}**
```

This code is working good but `\addplot [gray] fill between[of=toppath and botpath];`creats a problem. The sphere slides to the left. Please help.
[image]

Comment: You can see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481283/intersection-of-a-sphere-and-a-plane-knowing-equations

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I'm encountering challenges while attempting to create a plot. I am quite new to latex. Would you be willing to extend your kindness by providing me with the necessary code? Your help would be greatly valued and immensely beneficial in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=120,theta=70},line cap=butt,
            line join=round,declare function={R=3;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
            \path
            (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            ;
        \draw[blue,3d/screen coords] (O) circle[radius=R];
        
            \shade[ball color=white,3d/screen coords,opacity=0.7] (O) circle[radius=R];
            \path pic[blue]{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)}}};
            \path  pic[red]{3d/circle on sphere={R=R, n={(1,0,1)}}}; %(1,0,1) is normal vector of the equation x + z = 0
\draw[3d/hidden] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,R)  (O)--(R,0,0) (O)--(0,R,0);
            
\draw[3d/visible, -stealth] (R,0,0) -- (R + 4,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[3d/visible,-stealth] (0,R,0) -- (0,R + 1,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[3d/visible, -stealth] (0,0,R) -- (0,0,R + 1.5) node[above]{$z$};
\path foreach \p/\g in {O/150}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.2] (-R,R+1,R) -- (R,R+1,-R) -- (R,-R-1,-R) --(-R,-R-1,R) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run with `lualatex`, but it needs some time to calculate the intersection:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-3)(2,4)
\psset{viewpoint=50 100 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=70,lightsrc=-20 50 20}
\axesIIID(2.5,6,2)
\psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[-1 0 1 0]},base=-1 2 -2 2,
  ngrid=40 40,fillcolor=red!30,linewidth=0pt,name=B1,action=none]
\psSolid[object=sphere,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=72 72,name=C1,action=none](1,0,0)
\psSolid[object=fusion,linewidth=0.01pt,base=B1_s C1,linewidth=0.01pt,]
\defFunction[algebraic]{Circle}(t){0.5+0.5*cos(t)}{1/sqrt(2)*sin(t)}{0.5+0.5*cos(t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,r=0,function=Circle,range=0 3.14,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking great... Thank you. Is the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: Yes, taking time... compile timed out in overleaf

Comment: for overleaf use xelatex or latex->dvips-ps2pdf (fast). Yes the sphere has radius r=1