# Help Me to Create Animation from Still Tikz-3D Image with changing value of one variable

Tags: animations, tikz-3d

I am just learning tikz with still image. This is my first trying to create animation.

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\colorlet{mild}{ocre!50}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-0.385cm)},z={(0,1cm)},scale=1.25]
        \fill[rotate around z=10, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:360:1);
        \draw (0,0,2) circle (1);
        \draw[rotate around z=40, dashed] (1,0,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,0,2);
        \draw[rotate around z=40] (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw (-1,0,0) -- (-1,0,2);
        \draw (1,0,0) -- (1,0,2);
        \draw[rotate around z=40, scale=0.8] (0,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0);
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{40}{0};
            \fill[mild,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
            \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,1,0) circle (1);
            \draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,2,0) -- (0,0,0);
            \draw (1,0,1) arc (0:180:1);
            \draw[dashed] (-1,0,1) arc (180:360:1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that if I change the value of $z$ here:

```
    \fill[rotate around z=10, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
```

from z=20, to z=10, to z=0, z = -10, z = -20, etc. it will make the orange shade circling 360 degree. I want this animation. How to create it.

Including the orange shade of the sphere too, can we create the animation of the shade circling 360 degree?

[image: 1]

Comment: See here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480718/how-can-i-draw-this-cylinder-with-3d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tikzpicture` can be parameterised by wrapping it in a command that takes one mandatory argument, the rotation angle about the *z* axis. Within the `tikzpicture`, the rotation angle to be parameterised is replaced with the command argument `#1`, i. e.:

```
\fill[rotate around z=#1, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
```

Then, the command is placed in the body of a loop making command, such as `\multiframe` of pkg `animate`, which passes a sequence of rotation angles.

[image]

Note that two `;` where too much in the original implementation, leading to a `Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!` warning. Also, the code was slightly modified to allow for dashed hidden lines for rotation angles > 180°.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\colorlet{mild}{ocre!50}

% parameterised tikzpicture with one parameter (rot angle about z)
\NewDocumentCommand\parampicture{m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-0.385cm)},z={(0,1cm)},scale=1.25]
    \fill[rotate around z=#1, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:360:1);
    \draw (0,0,2) circle (1);
    \draw[rotate around z=#1, dashed] (1,0,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,0,2);
    \draw[rotate around z=#1] (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2);
    \draw[rotate around z=#1, \ifnum#1>180 dashed\fi] (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0);
    \draw (-1,0,0) -- (-1,0,2);
    \draw (1,0,0) -- (1,0,2);
    \draw[rotate around z=#1, scale=0.8] (0,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
      \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{#1}{0}
      \fill[mild,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
      \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, \ifnum#1>180 dashed\fi] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
      \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}
      \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,1,0) circle (1);
      \draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,2,0) -- (0,0,0);
      \draw (1,0,1) arc (0:180:1);
      \draw[dashed] (-1,0,1) arc (180:360:1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage[export]{animate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{25}
  \multiframe{360}{i=0+1}{
    \parampicture{\i}
  }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

To get a PDF animation for Okular or Acrobat Reader, remove the `export` option from `animate`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much

Comment: I get errors: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/##1>180 dashed' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...ot_rotated_coords, \ifnum#1>180 dashed\fi]`

Comment: this too: `Package xkeyval Error: `export' undefined in families `anim@pkg'. \expandafter\@anim@setpkgkeys\@anim@pkgopts`

Comment: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@expression. \draw[rotate around z=#1, scale=0.8]`

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code block below "Complete Code" unmodified into a text file `something.tex` and process it with `pdflatex`? This should work without error using an up-to-date TeX installation, such as MiKTeX or TeXLive-2022, or maybe using an online service such as Overleaf.

Comment: I am using TeX Studio. with Linux OS. TexLive I am using is 2021. Tell me a link or tutorial to upgrade TexLive then.. it must be the outdated version of mine.

Comment: I tested with texlive-2021 and it worked too. The "`export undefined in families anim@pkg`" error is somewhat disturbing. It looks as if an ancient `animate.sty` package file is loaded. The `export` option first appeared in 8/2018. Could you please look for `animate.sty` files on your computer and delete those outside the TeXLive installation?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a suggestion but too long to be a comment. The [animation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672165/help-me-to-create-animation-from-still-tikz-3d-image-with-changing-value-of-one/672187#672187) offered by [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) is very good, and my animation is essentially the same.

What I'm changing is the 3d view for one more realistic, specially for the sphere. For this I'd use `3d` and `perspective` Ti*k*Z libraries. I'll need `intersections` too, to set the visibility with a `\clip`.

This is my approach:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,intersections,perspective}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\tikzset
{% styles
   not visible/.style={draw=gray,very thin},% <--- change it for dashed if you prefer
   section/.style={not visible,fill=ocre,fill opacity=0.5},
}

% parameterised tikzpicture with three parameters
% #1 = rotation angle around z,
% #2 = 3d view angle azimuth,
% #3 = 3d view angle elevation > 0 !!!
\NewDocumentCommand\parampicture{mmm}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,3d view={#2}{#3}]
    % cylinder
    \draw[not visible] (#2-180:1) arc (#2-180:#2-360:1);
    \begin{scope}[rotate around z=#1+#2,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
      \fill[section]     (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
      \draw[not visible] (0,0.25) -| (0.25,0);
      \draw              (0,2)    -- (1,2) \ifnum#1>180 -- (1,0)\fi;
    \end{scope}
    \draw (#2-180:1) ++  (0,0,2)  --++ (0,0,-2) arc (#2-180:#2:1) --++ (0,0,2);
    \draw (0,0,2) circle (1);    
    % sphere
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#2:2.5)}]
      \path[name path=sphere] (0,0,1) circle (0.999cm);% Ooops, TikZ precision!!!
      \draw[not visible]      (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2);
      \begin{scope}[rotate around z=#2,canvas is xy plane at z=1]
        \draw[not visible] (1,0) arc (0: 180:1);
        \draw              (1,0) arc (0:-180:1);
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[rotate around z=#1+#2,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
        \draw[section,name path=semicircle] (0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
        \path[name intersections={of=sphere and semicircle}];
        \clip[overlay] (0,1) -- (intersection-1) --++ (2,0) |- (-1,3) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
      \end{scope}
      \draw (0,0,1) circle (1cm);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{25}
    % better to avoid a frame with i=90
    \multiframe{90}{i=0+4}{\parampicture{\i}{130}{30}}
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have errors can't produce both the animations above and yours. Tell me is TexStudio unable to produce animation? What should I use then for 3D animation in Tikz LaTeX?

Comment: `Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `##' or `##2' (in '##2'). ... (0,0,2) --++ (0,0,-2) arc (#2-180:#2:1)`

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess, both work fine in my PC with TeXlive 2022. The problem could be you LaTeX distribution (not TeXstudio). Perhaps you need to update it?

Comment: Yes I will, update it, I know it is troublesome 1 year not updating..

Comment: This looks impressive! +1.

Comment: @AlexG, thanks!! As I said, I only changed the view, the rest is all yours :-)