# Strange lines in a shade of the object

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'm trying to depict a sphere with shading

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2.5]
        \def\spradius{1}
        % draws a shaded sphere
        \shade[ball color = lightgray, opacity = 0.5] (0,0,0) circle (\spradius cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After compiling I have a next pdf image
[image: How it looks in pdf]

But then I run a convert to png

> magick convert -density 600 -depth 24 -quality 100 .pdf
>   .png

on this pdf and get
[image: png after conversion]

So those black lines become apparent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Exactly** how are you converting to PNG?

Comment: magick convert -density 600 -depth 24 -quality 100

Comment: It seems to be dependent of the resolution, try a much much higher density and then resample it down later

Comment: No lines with 3600 to a tif and then to png

Comment: I've used a resample -600, but the lines are there - you can see them in zoomin. Is it some layer in pdf that should be ignored?

Comment: Can you check whether the addendum [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446288) allows you to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. This solves the problem.

Comment: No problem with a direct convertion to PNG with PDF-XChange.

Answer (score 1):

The point is the installed version of Ghostscript: Magick uses Ghostscript to convert PDF files into raster images. In some versions, shaded balls have this issue.

A possible solution is installing a newer version of Ghostscript before converting the PDFs. I had the same issue with Ghostscript v9.26, but after installing v9.54 (the most recent stable release at the time of writing) the lines disappeared.

I've used the following string to convert both images:

```
convert -density 600 -depth 24 -quality 100 .pdf .png
```

[image: My sphere with GhostScript v9.26]
[image: My sphere with GhostScript v9.54]