# Problem using .estyle in a tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf

I copied Tomasz M. Trzeciak's code from [Elliptic Moebius map on sphere using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94070/elliptic-moebius-map-on-sphere-using-tikz) to draw a shaded sphere with parallels and meridians. Only the sphere was drawn - no parallels or meridians. When I changed the `\tikzset(#1/.estyle` to `\tikzset(#1/.style` in the LongitudePlane and LatitudePlane macros the lines were correctly drawn.
I am running the latest version of OS X 10.9.3 and have the full Mac Latex install with the latest updates (as far as I can tell).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Besides elaborate more the question, could you also put a reference to Tomasz M. Trzeciak's code?

Comment: This is introduced in TikZ v3.00 I think. I remember vaguely about a bug report.

Comment: @percusse May be [ticket #306](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/306/)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Looks like it indeed

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness! I think there is a bug with /.estyle under the current release of LaTeX and Mavericks. I am exploring the steriographic drawing ability of Tex with TiKz and discovered that when running the code from  [link] (http://http:www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/) on my Mac I didn't get any of the lines of latitude and longitude drawn. Changing the /.estyle to /.style produced the lines but then some of the other graphics were not drawn.

Comment: This problem was all about the way the /.prefix Key Handler works. On my latest Mac installation if you attempt to /.prefix a style to an existing /.estyle the expanded macro includes a /noexpand after the prefix so that the original key code is NEVER expanded! Chaos ensues as you would imagine! Simply creating another key for the prefix and then 'manually' inserting it with the prefixed style works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the [Stereographic and cylindrical map projections example of Tomas M. Trzeciak](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/) only when I used pgf/tikz-Vers.3.0 and not the version 2.0.

In this case i replaced \tikzset(#1/.estyle with \tikzset(#1/.style and the 3d sphere was printed as expected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for your answer, we're looking forward to your future contributions to this Q&A.