# Why doesn't prefixing an estyle work

Tags: tikz-pgf

Prefixing a style to a previously created `/.estyle` using the current (June 2014) iteration of Mac Latex inserts a `\noexpand` before the original style. As you can imagine this causes chaos! Bug?

Comment: Related: [Problem using .estyle in a tikzset](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181252/problem-using-estyle-in-a-tikzset)

Comment: Use `/.expanded` if this is an issue

Comment: Having figured the issue out I prefer to create the required prefix code and explicitly add it in front of the style code, e.g. \draw[my scale, my style] ...

Comment: @adlibber : Is the question still open or could write an [accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer that worked for you? Otherwise we could close the question.