# How to draw a squeezed ellipse with fading color on a sphere surface with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, 3d, shapes

Ideally, I would like to draw something like part (c) of the image below:
[image: ellipsonsphere]
<sub>(source: [nbi.ku.dk](http://quantop.nbi.ku.dk/research/nanofiber/spin_squeezing/figure6a-c.png))</sub>
. Here, I narrow down the question to how to draw an ellipse on the surface of a sphere with fading color as shown on part (b) of the figure. (Note: Maybe I can follow [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz?rq=1) to draw arrows on the surface of the sphere to finish (c) from (b)).

1. The first attempt is to basically follow [a simple example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/) to draw the sphere, and found that it did not work out for the current version of TikZ. Now I stuck at this step. Here is my minimum code on finishing a part of this job for the first attempt:

   ```
   \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} %\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows,math}
   \begin{document}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
   \newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos3{%
     \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
     \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
   }
   \newcommand\LongitudePlane3[current plane]{%
     \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
     \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
     \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
   }
   \newcommand\LatitudePlane3[current plane]{%
     \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
     \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
     \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
     \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
   }
   \newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle2{
     \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
     \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
      % angle of "visibility"
     \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
     \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
     \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
   }
   \newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle2{
     \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
     \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
     % angle of "visibility"
     \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
     \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
     \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
   }
   ```

   %% document-wide tikz options and styles

   \tikzset{%

   > =latex, % option for nice arrows
   >     inner sep=0pt,%
   >     outer sep=2pt,%
   >     mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
   >       fill=black,circle}%
   >   }

   \begin{figure}[ht]
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tikzpicture} % MERC

   % Modified from Stereographic and cylindrical map projections
   % Author: Tomasz M. Trzeciak
   % Source: LaTeX-Community.org 
   %         http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2111

   %% some definitions

   \def\R{3} % sphere radius
   \def\angEl{25} % elevation angle
   \def\angAz{-100} % azimuth angle
   \def\angPhiOne{-50} % longitude of point P
   \def\angPhiTwo{-35} % longitude of point Q
   \def\angBeta{33} % latitude of point P and Q

   %% working planes

   \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
   \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
   \LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiOne}
   \LongitudePlane[qzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhiTwo}
   \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

   %% draw background sphere

   \fill[ball color=white] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
   %\fill[white] (0,0) circle (\R); % just a white circle
   \draw (0,0) circle (\R);

   %% characteristic points

   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
   \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
   \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);
   \path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);
   \path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
   \path[qzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (Q);
   \path[qzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (QE);

   %% meridians and latitude circles

   % \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz} % xzplane
   % \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz+90} % yzplane
   \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiOne} % pzplane
   %\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhiTwo} % qzplane
   \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\angBeta}
   \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator

   % shifted equator in node with nested call to tikz 
   % (I didn't know it's possible)
   %\node at (0,1.6*\R) { \tikz{\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0}} };

   %% draw lines and put labels

   %\draw (-\R,-\H) -- (-\R,2*\R) (\R,-\H) -- (\R,2*\R);
   %\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,1.5*\R) node[above] {$|0\rangle$};
   \node[above=8pt] at (N) {$|0\rangle$};%{$\mathbf{N}$};
   \node[below=8pt] at (S) {$|1\rangle$};%{$\mathbf{S}$};
   \node[right=8pt] at (P) {$|\Phi \rangle$};
   \draw[->] (O) -- (P);
   \draw[dashed] (O) -- (N);
   \draw[dashed] (XE) -- (O) -- (PE);
   %\draw[dashed] (O) -- (QE);
   %\draw[pzplane,->,thin] (0:0.5*\R) to[bend right=15]
   %    node[midway,right] {$\beta$} (\angBeta:0.5*\R);
   \path[pzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) ;%node[right] {$\hat{1}$};
   \path[qzplane] (0.5*\angBeta:\R) ;%node[right] {$\hat{2}$};
   \draw[equator,->,thin] (\angAz:0.5*\R) to[bend right=30]
       node[pos=0.4,above] {$\phi$} (\angPhiOne:0.5*\R);
   \draw[pzplane,->,thin] (90:0.5*\R) to[bend left=30]
       node[midway,right] {$\theta$} (\angBeta:0.5*\R);
   \draw[equator,->] (-90:\R) arc (-90:-70:\R) ;%node[below=0.3ex] {$x = a\phi$};
   \path[xzplane] (0:\R) node[below] {$\theta=0$};
   \path[xzplane] (\angBeta:\R);% node[below left] {$\beta=\beta_0$};

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
   \caption{Ellipse on a Sphere}
   \label{fig:sphere}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}

Preview: [image]
As you can see, compared with [the original example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/) (the lower-left plot), the two dashed lines on the equator cannot show up in my modified version. This error occurs even when I compile the code of the original example. Noticed that I have replaced **estyle** to **style**. Most importantly, what should I do next to make the ellipse and fading colors on the sphere at an arbitrary position? Thanks again.

2. The second attempt is to use `3dplot` to finish the sphere, and the code is very simple (with imperfections). Below is the code:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
   %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
   \begin{document}
   \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7,>=latex,shape=circle]
   \pgfsetlinewidth{.1pt}]
   %draw sphere
   \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot{36}{12}{1}{black!85!white}{blue!40!white}
   {\draw[color=black,thick,->]  (-1.5,0,0) --  (1.5,0,0)  node[anchor=north  east]{$x$};}
   {\draw[color=black,thick,->]  (0,-1.5,0) --  (0,1.5,0)  node[anchor=north  west]{$y$};}
   {\draw[color=black,thick,->]  (0,0,-1.5) --  (0,0,1.5)  node[anchor=south]{$z$};}
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   and the preview: [image: spherein3dplot]

I don't know how to do the ellipse next. Thoughts?

Comment: Why did you replace `estyle` by `style`?

Comment: @cfr This is due to the version change of TikZ. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181252/problem-using-estyle-in-a-tikzset) to correctly show the longitude and latitude lines. But the dashed lines from the origin to the equator are still not showing up in my case.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Just I knew that `estyle` was still supported (according to the documentation) and so couldn't figure out why you'd change it. A bug explains that!

Answer (score 7):

Here an alternative to get to the desired image. I did just an approximation (no mathematical correct drawing) on the path on the globe. See this as a simple how to.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(215:.75cm)},y={(-10:1cm)},z={(90:1cm)}]

    % Axes
    \begin{scope}[black!50, >=latex, ->, font=\scriptsize]
        \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(1.5,0,0) coordinate [label={0:$x$}];
        \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(0,1.5,0) coordinate [label={35:$y$}];
        \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,1.5) coordinate [label={90:$z$}];
    \end{scope}

    % Globe
    \begin{scope}[blue!50!white, samples=250, domain=0:2*pi]
        \draw plot ({cos(\x r)}, {sin(\x r)}, 0); % xy
        \draw plot ({cos(\x r)}, 0, {sin(\x r)}); % xz
        \draw plot (0, {cos(\x r)}, {sin(\x r)}); % yz
        \fill [opacity=.5] (0,0) circle (.85cm);
    \end{scope}

    % Plot around globe - just approximation!
    \begin{scope}[smooth, red, >=latex, ->, scale=.85]
        \draw [domain=0:.875] plot ({cos(\x r)},{sin(\x r)},0);
        \draw [domain=.19:pi/3.5] plot ({cos(\x r)},{cos(\x r)},{sin(\x r)}) coordinate (c-x);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[on background layer, smooth]
        % projection area with plot
        \fill [blue!50!white] (-4,-1.5,-1.5) -- (-4,1.5,-1.5) -- (-4,1.5,1.5) -- (-4,-1.5,1.5);
        \draw [black!25, very thin] (-4,0,-1.5) -- (-4,0,1.5);
        \draw [black!25, very thin] (-4,-1.5,0) -- (-4,1.5,0);
        \draw [black!75, domain=-1.5:1.5] plot (-4,{\x},{sin((2*\x) r)});
        \draw [black!25, domain=-1.5:1.5] plot (-4,{\x},{0.8*sin((2*\x) r)});

        % grey filled circle
        \fill [black!15, opacity=.5] (0,0,0) circle (1.155cm);

        % projection of globe-coordinate
        \draw [dashed] (c-x) -- +(-4,0,0);
    \end{scope}     
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: This looks good! But how to draw the projected ellipse on the surface of the sphere?