# Plot latitude and longitude lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having problems finding how to draw a longitude line like the one show in the figure. I do not want to have a complicate drawing just similar to the one in the picture. I have found some order entries about this issue but are related with more complicated views of a 3d sphere. The problem is hoot draw an arc that passes by the two poles.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This has all been worked out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49589/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/121799). (At least I think these are the most original posts.)

Comment: Not really, I would like the North and South Poles to be in the upper and downer part of the spare. The plot That I need is much easier that the ones showed in the post. Thanks

Comment: Well, these links show how one can draw latitude circles and longitude arcs. What is wrong with taking one of them and drawing these curves using the methods developed there?

Comment: I thought I would be an easier way of doing it. A complicate code for a beginner.

Comment: Of course you could just add a cartoon. Or, since you seem not to be interested in distinguishing between hidden  visible parts, you could just use `tikz-3dplot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one can draw such things without caring about whether or nor some element is hidden. Personally like those things produced by [these macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49589/121799), [these tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/121799) and many other posts here *much* better. (If are saying that these should be parts of some packages by now, I would immediately agree, though.) **UPDATE**: Hide the hidden part of the longitude arc.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{105}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,font=\sffamily,line join=bevel]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{3} % radius
\draw[thick,gray,dashed] (0,0,-\R-1) -- (0,0,\R+1);
\begin{scope}
\clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},0)
-- plot[variable=\x,domain=180:0,tdplot_screen_coords] ({\R*cos(\x)},{-\R*sin(\x)});
\shade[ball color=gray,opacity=0.2] [tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\R);
\end{scope}
\draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\R);
% equator
\draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.15] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},0);
% upper latitude circle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lat}{48}
\draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.15] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth] 
({\R*cos(\x)*sin(\Lat)},{\R*sin(\x)*sin(\Lat)},{\R*cos(\Lat)});
% longitude halfcircle with extensions
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lon}{50}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetacrit}{atan(cos(\tdplotmaintheta)/(sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\Lon)))}
\draw[thick,gray] (0,0,-\R-1) -- (0,0,-\R) 
plot[variable=\x,domain={180+\thetacrit}:0,smooth] 
({\R*cos(\Lon)*sin(\x)},{\R*sin(\Lon)*sin(\x)},{\R*cos(\x)})
-- (0,0,\R+1) node[black,above left] {axis of rotation};
\draw[thick] ({\R*cos(\Lon)*sin(90)},{\R*sin(\Lon)*sin(90)},{\R*cos(90)})
-- (0,0,0) -- ({\R*cos(\Lon)*sin(\Lat)},{\R*sin(\Lon)*sin(\Lat)},{\R*cos(\Lat)})
coordinate (L);
\draw[thick,gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=90:\Lat,smooth] 
({0.7*\R*cos(\Lon)*sin(\x)},{0.7*\R*sin(\Lon)*sin(\x)},{0.7*\R*cos(\x)});
\node [tdplot_screen_coords] at (1,0.4) {$\lambda$};
\draw[orange,tdplot_screen_coords] (L) to[out=0,in=180] ++ (2,1) node[right]{$\lambda=$latitude};
\draw[fill=blue] (L) circle (2pt);
\path (0,0,\R) coordinate (N) (0,0,-\R) coordinate (S) (-\R,0,0) coordinate (W)
({\R*cos(\Lon)*sin(135)},{\R*sin(\Lon)*sin(135)},{\R*cos(135)}) coordinate (M);
\draw[-latex,very thick,gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=150:30,smooth] 
({cos(\x)*sin(\Lat)},{sin(\x)*sin(\Lat)},{\R+0.5});
\draw ([xshift=-2mm]W) -- ++ (-1,0) node[left]{equator}
(N) to[out=180,in=0] ++ (-2,0.2cm) node[left]{north pole}
(S) to[out=180,in=0] ++ (-2,-0.2cm) node[left]{south pole};
\draw[orange,tdplot_screen_coords] (M) -- ++ (0.2,-1) node[below]{meridian};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]