# Draw a non-geodesic rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I try to draw this image.
[image]
where `$\alpha_1$` and `$\alpha_2$` are circumferences in the unit sphere, passing through `C=(1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3))` with center at the origin of coordinates, that is, they are geodesic. It is not necessary to graph `$\alpha_1$` or `$\alpha_2$`, but it would look nice if it were done.. I have some complications like for example the label comes out too big. I don't know how to rotate the graphic to make it look like my image. I don't know how to paint that little rectangle, either with lines or a whole color. Any suggestion?
On the other hand, I would also like the contour of the sphere to appear with a not so thick line, I tried to do it by plotting the largest circumference but if I plan to rotate it it does not work for me that is why I did not put it in the code.

[image]
This is my code,

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newrgbcolor{mycolor}{0 153 216}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[ball color=mycolor]  (0,0) circle (1cm); 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{25/16};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\a/(sqrt(3))};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{sqrt(1-\d*\d)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1/sqrt(2)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{1/sqrt(6)};


\pgfmathsetmacro{\aa}{53/32};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dd}{\aa/(sqrt(3))};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{sqrt(1-\dd*\dd)};


\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=360:0,samples=181] 
({\a/3+\e*\r*cos(\x)-\f*\r*sin(\x)},{\a/3-\e*\r*cos(\x)-\f*\r*sin(\x)},{\a/3+2*\f*\r*sin(\x)});

\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=360:0,samples=181] 
({\aa/3+\e*\rr*cos(\x)-\f*\rr*sin(\x)},{\aa/3-\e*\rr*cos(\x)-\f*\rr*sin(\x)},{\aa/3+2*\f*\rr*sin(\x)});

\draw[fill] ({1/sqrt(3)},{1/sqrt(3)},{1/sqrt(3)}) circle (0.02) node[below left] {$C$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to load `pstricks-add` just to define a new color. You can do this just with
`\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0, 153, 216}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has already been made some effort to simplify drawing on spheres in [this amazing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/47927) (therefore, credit should go to the author of the linked answer, too). I took over the idea and two of the basic code components from there and created something that you might be able to use:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Style to set camera angle, like PGFPlots `view` style
\tikzset{viewport/.style 2 args={
    x={({cos(-#1)*1cm},{sin(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    y={({-sin(-#1)*1cm},{cos(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    z={(0,{cos(#2)*1cm})}
}}

% Convert from spherical to cartesian coordinates
\newcommand{\ToXYZ}[2]{
    {sin(#1)*cos(#2)}, % X coordinate
    {cos(#1)*cos(#2)}, % Y coordinate
    {sin(#2)}          % Z (vertical) coordinate
}

\begin{document}
\def\RotationX{-10}
\def\RotationY{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \path[draw] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[viewport={\RotationX}{\RotationY}]

        \draw[variable=\t, smooth] 
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:-90-\RotationY] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:-90-\RotationX] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});
        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth]
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:270-\RotationY] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:270-\RotationX] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});
            
        \draw[red, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360] 
            plot (\ToXYZ{20*sin(\t)}{20*cos(\t)}) 
            plot (\ToXYZ{10*sin(\t)}{10*cos(\t)});
        
        \fill[blue, opacity=.25, variable=\t, smooth] 
            plot[domain=0:90] (\ToXYZ{20*sin(\t)}{20*cos(\t)}) -- 
            plot[domain=10:20] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0}) --
            plot[domain=90:0] (\ToXYZ{10*sin(\t)}{10*cos(\t)}) -- 
            plot[domain=10:20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t}) --
            cycle;

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={240:$C$}] at (\ToXYZ{0}{0}) {};

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={90:$P$}] at (\ToXYZ{10*sin(30)}{10*cos(30)}) {};

    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to draw great circles other than these two regular ones, the easiest way would probably be to rotate them using the option `rotate around y`. Then you don't need to do the math.

For the marked area, you can simply adjust the `domain` option and specify other angles.

One example with one of the great circles turned by −20° and the marked area adjusted respectively (covering now 110° of the part between the two red circles):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Style to set camera angle, like PGFPlots `view` style
\tikzset{viewport/.style 2 args={
    x={({cos(-#1)*1cm},{sin(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    y={({-sin(-#1)*1cm},{cos(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    z={(0,{cos(#2)*1cm})}
}}

% Convert from spherical to cartesian coordinates
\newcommand{\ToXYZ}[2]{
    {sin(#1)*cos(#2)}, % X coordinate
    {cos(#1)*cos(#2)}, % Y coordinate
    {sin(#2)}          % Z (vertical) coordinate
}

\begin{document}
\def\RotationX{-10}
\def\RotationY{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \path[draw] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[viewport={\RotationX}{\RotationY}]

        \draw[variable=\t, smooth] 
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:-90-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:-90-\RotationX] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});
        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth]
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:270-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:270-\RotationX] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});

        \draw[red, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360] 
            plot (\ToXYZ{20*sin(\t)}{20*cos(\t)}) 
            plot (\ToXYZ{10*sin(\t)}{10*cos(\t)});
        
        \fill[blue, opacity=.25, variable=\t, smooth] 
            plot[domain=-20:90] (\ToXYZ{20*sin(\t)}{20*cos(\t)}) -- 
            plot[domain=10:20] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0}) --
            plot[domain=90:-20] (\ToXYZ{10*sin(\t)}{10*cos(\t)}) -- 
            plot[domain=10:20, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t}) --
            cycle;

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={240:$C$}] at (\ToXYZ{0}{0}) {};

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={90:$P$}] at (\ToXYZ{10*sin(30)}{10*cos(30)}) {};

    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: In case you find that the paths are not plotted smoothly enough, you can add the option `samples=` (like in your example) and state a number that is high enough to satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much the graph is great, a question if I want the separation of the curves that pass through `C` to have a particular angle for example `120` or `150`?.

Comment: @Zaragosa I added a simple way to adjust the angle of the great circles and of the marked area.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It's fantastic!

Comment: I corrected the path for the marked areas. I had cheated a bit and had just drawn sraight lines where the path that demarcates the area runs along the great circles. Now, it is precise. The correction is hardly visible anyways.

Comment: Thank you, I left my final product as an answer, with the sole purpose that people can see what my initial idea was like, and thanks to your help I was able to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much for Jasper Habicht's answer, here I will leave the modifications that I made (just so that future people can see how everything turned out):
[image]

I made the code before your last modification:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0, 153, 216}

% Style to set camera angle, like PGFPlots `view` style
\tikzset{viewport/.style 2 args={
    x={({cos(-#1)*1cm},{sin(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    y={({-sin(-#1)*1cm},{cos(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    z={(0,{cos(#2)*1cm})}
}}

% Convert from spherical to cartesian coordinates
\newcommand{\ToXYZ}[2]{
    {sin(#1)*cos(#2)}, % X coordinate
    {cos(#1)*cos(#2)}, % Y coordinate
    {sin(#2)}          % Z (vertical) coordinate
}

\begin{document}
\def\RotationX{-20}
\def\RotationY{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \path[ball color= mycolor, draw] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[viewport={\RotationX}{\RotationY}]

        \draw[variable=\t, smooth, line width=0.2pt] 
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:-90-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:-90-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});
            
        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth, line width=0.5pt, opacity=0.3]
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:270-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:270-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});
            
        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth]
            plot[domain=-160:-20] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)});
            
        \fill[color=blue!80!white, opacity=1, variable=\t, smooth] 
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{25*sin(\t)}{25*cos(\t)}) --
            plot[domain=201:-20] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)}) -- cycle;

        \draw[black, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360, line width=0.4pt] 
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{25*sin(\t)}{25*cos(\t)})
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)});
            
        \draw[black, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360, line width=0.4pt] 
            plot[domain=55-\RotationY:45-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=5-\RotationX:-5-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] at (\ToXYZ{0}{0}) {};

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] at (\ToXYZ{15*sin(140)}{15*cos(140)}) {};
        
        \node[] at (1,0.5,0.5) {\Large{$\mathbb S^2$}};
        \node[] at (-0.14,0.1,0.6) {\Large{$\gamma$}};
        \node[] at (-0.2,0.1,0.4) {\Large{$p$}};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```