# Draw in latex without downloading the pdf

Tags: graphics, miktex, overleaf, plot, includegraphics

A query I am trying to write in latex and attach this [image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623505/248335). I did it separately, downloaded the pdf file to keep its resolution and attached it to my latex file. Is there a way to do it directly without having to use this method? That is, I want to do everything in latex code, without downloading anything. It's possible?

I will attach a code to exemplify:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
The universe is immense and it seems to be homogeneous, 
in a large scale, everywhere we look at.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{tubularflow.pdf}
\end{figure}

text
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you mean can latex include an image over http, the answer is no.

Comment: but the referenced image is just a tikz picure, so naurally you can put that tex source in your main document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is solved by @David Carlisle comment. In the case, that you like to include code for image from the link in your question, you can do on the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% part preamble needed for your image
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0, 153, 216}

% Style to set camera angle, like PGFPlots `view` style
\tikzset{viewport/.style 2 args={
    x={({cos(-#1)*1cm},{sin(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    y={({-sin(-#1)*1cm},{cos(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
    z={(0,{cos(#2)*1cm})}
}}

% Convert from spherical to cartesian coordinates
\newcommand{\ToXYZ}[2]{
    {sin(#1)*cos(#2)}, % X coordinate
    {cos(#1)*cos(#2)}, % Y coordinate
    {sin(#2)}          % Z (vertical) coordinate
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% other part preamble needed for your document 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
% code for image
\def\RotationX{-20}
\def\RotationY{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

    \path[ball color= mycolor, draw] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[viewport={\RotationX}{\RotationY}]

        \draw[variable=\t, smooth, line width=0.2pt]
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:-90-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:-90-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});

        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth, line width=0.5pt, opacity=0.3]
            plot[domain=90-\RotationY:270-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=90-\RotationX:270-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});

        \draw[densely dashed, variable=\t, smooth]
            plot[domain=-160:-20] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)});

        \fill[color=blue!80!white, opacity=1, variable=\t, smooth]
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{25*sin(\t)}{25*cos(\t)}) --
            plot[domain=201:-20] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)}) -- cycle;

        \draw[black, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360, line width=0.4pt]
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{25*sin(\t)}{25*cos(\t)})
            plot[domain=-21:201] (\ToXYZ{15*sin(\t)}{15*cos(\t)});

        \draw[black, variable=\t, smooth, domain=0:360, line width=0.4pt]
            plot[domain=55-\RotationY:45-\RotationY, rotate around y=-20] (\ToXYZ{0}{\t})
            plot[domain=5-\RotationX:-5-\RotationX, rotate around y=110] (\ToXYZ{\t}{0});

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] at (\ToXYZ{0}{0}) {};

        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] at (\ToXYZ{15*sin(140)}{15*cos(140)}) {};

        \node[] at (1,0.5,0.5) {\Large{$\mathbb S^2$}};
        \node[] at (-0.14,0.1,0.6) {\Large{$\gamma$}};
        \node[] at (-0.2,0.1,0.4) {\Large{$p$}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unverse ...}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know where my mistake was. Thank you very much. An additional query, is it possible to have the graph code (with all its usepackage environment, definitions, etc) apart and only call it so that it can be graphed? I'm thinking of making several graphics and it would be quite heavy to have it all together, that's why my question. Is there any way to "scale" with this way of graphing? Or should I do that directly in the code of the graph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zaragosa, yes,  in generally it it is possible. However, it is not straightforward. Some hints: image file had to use `standalone` document class, main document had to load package `standalone`.  Both should have some common part of preambles, specific definitions had to be inside image document, etc .  I suggest you to ask new question visible to more people who will able to help you.