Draw an arc in 3dtools
I've been trying to figure out how to use 3dtools to draw celestial diagrams.
I have an issue in that I'm unsure on the correct syntax to use to draw part of an arc lying on a sphere. For example, in the following MWE, I would like to draw an arc through the points S', Z', and N' with the arc extending about 10 degrees past point N'.
Any suggestions on how to go about this?

\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=0,theta=-30,psi=-60},declare function={R=8;}] 
%theta moves around x-axis = EW
%psi moves around y-axis = Zenith
%phi moves around z-axis = NS

\path  (0,0,0) coordinate (O) 

\coordinate [fill,circle, inner sep=1pt,label=$W$] (W) at (R,0,0)  {}; 
\coordinate [fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$E(\alpha_0)$](E) at (-R,0,0) {}; 
\coordinate [fill,circle, inner sep=1pt,label=$N'$] (N) at (0,0,R) {}; 
\coordinate [fill,circle, inner sep=1pt,label=$S'$] (S) at (0,0,-R) {}; 
\coordinate[fill,circle, inner sep = 1pt,label=$Z'$] (Z) at (0,R,0) {}; 


\draw [3d/screen coords] (E) -- (W);
\draw [3d/screen coords] (N) -- (S);
\draw [3d/screen coords] (Z) -- (O);

\draw[3d/screen coords] (O) circle[radius=R]; 
   
\path 
%horizon
pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},n={(0,1,0)}}}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I've tried to add an arc using
\draw (S) arc (0:180:R);

But all it does is add a 180 degrees arc that's in the same plane as the unrotated diagram. I'm sure there must be a way for me to specify that the arc should be in a different plane. Can someone help out?


Interesting library. How did you find it?

minhthien-2016 shared it with me at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718639/easiest-way-to-draw-celestial-sphere-diagrams/718663?noredirect=1#comment1786991_718663

I added a link to the library. feel free to revert if you are unhappy about this. you might also add a link to that question into yours.

That's perfect. Thank you!

Thanks. I assumed that there will have to be some specification as to different coordinates, but the 3dtools manual doesn't specify how to do this. The problem is that it doesn't seem like many people on here know how to use 3dtools. I really wish someone would actually be able to show me the ropes.

Have you tried this search? https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=3dtools At least you’ll learn something about this library through the lense of problems.
