Draw a three dimensional sphere with TikZ that looks like this
I would like to draw a simple sphere with radius 1 in a three dimensional coordinate system that has some kind of grid on its surface, i.e. like in the following picture that I found.

I was wondering why I couldn't find anything regarding this. Is there any way to reproduce this graph with TikZ?

Welcome! If you mean you searched this site, you didn't find anything because the search function sucks. Try your favourite internet search engine with a site modifier. Or look at the links to the right (which are generally better than search). Search is also better while you ask a question for some reason. If you need help, though, please provide code to show what you've tried. You probably don't mean it to, but your question may otherwise look like a do-it-for-me. You can use tikz, pgfplots, metapost, asymptote or ... to draw this. The choice is yours.

Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199161/parabolic-moebius-map-on-sphere-using-tikz may be even better.
