Quiver plot on surface
Is it possible to combine a quiver plot and a surface plot, such that the z coordinate is respected?
From what I can find, z buffer = sort only works within one \addplot3 command, or is there a way around this?
The problem is that the arrows should sometimes be hidden behind the surface.
As a MWE, I've written down the code for the normal vectors of a ball.

The following old question is related: How can I draw a vector field (quiver plot) on a torus in 3D?
Feel free to give feedback on the code as well! I'm currently getting about 80 000 Missing character: There is no <character> in font nullfont! warnings..
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ compat = newest, colormap name = viridis }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        xfun(\u,\v) = sin(deg(\u))*cos(deg(\v));
        yfun(\u,\v) = sin(deg(\u)))*sin(deg(\v));
        zfun(\u,\v) = cos(deg(\u));
        usamples = 18;
        vsamples = 18;
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        axis equal image,
        z buffer = sort,
        ]
        \addplot3[
            variable = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            samples = {usamples},
            samples y = {vsamples},
            domain = 0:2*pi,
            domain y = 0:pi,
            surf,
            shader = faceted,
            thin,
        ] ( {xfun(\u,\v)}, {yfun(\u,\v)}, {zfun(\u,\v)} );
        \addplot3[
            variable = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            samples = {usamples/2},
            samples y = {vsamples},
            domain = 0:2*pi,
            domain y = 0:pi,
            -stealth,
            quiver = { 
                u = {xfun(\u,\v)},
                v = {yfun(\u,\v)},
                w = {zfun(\u,\v)},
                scale arrows = 0.3,
            }
        ] ( {xfun(\u,\v)}, {yfun(\u,\v)}, {zfun(\u,\v)} );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I like this! one way would be to implement the surface and vector field simultaneously (in external software), so you can sort them together (and with respect to the viewing plane's normal vector, instead of just the z-axis). I achieved something similar here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728413/319072

Do not use u and v (or w) as your independent variables in a quiver plot.

The z coordinate and the z buffer are two unrelated things. Obviously there is no issue with the z coordinate - it is respected - so probably just a writing error.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
fx(\s,\t)=sin(deg(\s))*cos(deg(\t));
fy(\s,\t)=sin(deg(\s)))*sin(deg(\t));
fz(\s,\t)=cos(deg(\s));
ss=18; st=18;
}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\azimuth}{25}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\elevation}{30}
\begin{axis}[
view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
hide axis,
axis equal image,
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraX}{sin(\azimuth)*cos(\elevation)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraY}{-cos(\azimuth)*cos(\elevation)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CameraZ}{sin(\elevation)}

\addplot3[
-{Stealth[scale=0.5]},
quiver={ u={fx(s,t)}, v={fy(s,t)}, w={fz(s,t)}, scale arrows=0.3},
domain=0:2*pi, samples=ss/2, variable=s,
domain y=0:pi, samples y=st, variable y=t,
] ({fx(s,t)},{fy(s,t)},{fz(s,t)});
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted,
z buffer=sort,
domain=0:2*pi, samples=ss, variable=s,
domain y=0:pi, samples y=st, variable y=t,
] ({fx(s,t)},{fy(s,t)},{fz(s,t)});
\addplot3[
-{Stealth[scale=0.5]},
quiver={ u={fx(s,t)}, v={fy(s,t)}, w={fz(s,t)}, scale arrows=0.3},
domain=0:2*pi, samples=ss/2, variable=s,
domain y=0:pi, samples y=st, variable y=t,
x filter/.expression={x*\CameraX+y*\CameraY+z*\CameraZ>0?x:nan},
filter discard warning=false,
] ({fx(s,t)},{fy(s,t)},{fz(s,t)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Same dot product methode as here:
How can I make a conditional which tests whether a point in 3d is in front of, or behind a plane?
and Camera vector from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/8650

Wow, great answer! Is there a way to solve this for more general 3D objects without the nice projection property of the ball? If not, is it possible to filter on s and t instead of x, y and z? Also, why did you use \pgfmathsetmacro instead of declaring these constants as functions?

There can not exist a general solution as the sphere and arrows can be in front or behind in arbitrary many zones which would need arbitrary many \addplot3

declare function is the same as \pgfmathdeclarefunction (and \pgfmathsetmacro) the reason I chose the later is because I wished to separate the general method from your declarations. You can definitely move everything inside the existing declare function if you wish.
